# Move to Online Mode only one site of two multi sites sharing the same code base

Tags: multi-sites

When I was working on one local site, I used to copy all the folders & files including the "sites" folder into my FTP account in addition to the database in order to have my local site online and be accessible by a specific domain name for example: www.FirstWebsite.com

However, Now I am using multi local sites (Two websites) on my laptop with separated databases, but sharing the same code base...
Which means the code base files for both websites are the same except the following folders which are specific for each website:
C:\DrupalSites\devdesktop\drupal-7.32\sites\FirstWebsite
C:\DrupalSites\devdesktop\drupal-7.32\sites\SecondWebsite

What are the files which I have to upload to my FTP Account in order for example to put only the website name: "Second Website" online ?!

Any help will be highly appreciated,,,
Thank you in advance...
             ---------------------------------------------------------------

Okay, i will rephrase my question... 
if you are working locally on one site named "FirstWebsite" and you want to host it online by using one of the hosting server available like for example "HostGator.com", you have only to transfer to the cpanel/file manger all the files and folders of your website .
However, when you want to create LOCALLY another website, you should make a multisite configuration . Whichmeans, all the folders will be used by both websites except the two folders named: "FirstWebsite" (for the existing website) & the "SecondWebsite" (the new folder created for the new website) .
Okay, So let say now we want to host online ONLY the new  website whom all its files are under the "SecondWebsite" Folder without hosting also the existing website whom all its files are under the "FirstWebsite" Folder .
Note: Do not forget that both websites are sharing the same code base.

My question: What folders and files i should transfer to the cpanel/file manager to ONLY host online the new website  whom basically all its files are under the "SecondWebsite" Folder?

Thank you very much for trying to understand my problem even if it is not well explained...

Comment: You can keep the same structure as your local setup, just upload everything except for /sites/secondwebsite.  Then only add your database for "firstwebsite"

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick Ryan for you help... I will try your suggestion, I think and hope that it will be the answer to my Problem...

Answer (score 0):

if you mean "update" with "put online" then it is not possible, because - as you pointed out - all sites share the same code base.. updating the sites/all folder will update both. the database updates need to be performed separately.

if you have only one website online that you want to update then just upload the changes from the sites/all folder.. that updates themes and modules.

cheers,
j

Comment: Dear schlicki, Thanks for your quick response but you got me wrong . what I meant by "Online" is "Moving off the site from the local host to an online hosting server so it can be accessible by anyone" .

Comment: I still don't completely understand. Do you have only one site online or is that also a multi site installation?
Basically the only files that are not shared by the single sites in a multi site environment are the files inside "FirstWebsite" and "SecondWebsite".